# PHP while...if statement not working, seems to ignore the ELSE

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anyone help, I have been trying to get this php code to work, with limited success, it seem the else statement in the while statement is being ignored, i have looked at other examples and just can't see what I've done wrong.  The code is used within a login form and the part that doesn't work is when a user inputs the wrong password. I am new to PHP and this is for a college assignment. I will include the code for the login page also.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//sanitize username
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

if($username&&$password) {
include 'db.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, salt
    FROM member
    WHERE username = '$username';");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$result = mysql_query($query);

$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$salt = $userData['salt'];
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . hash('sha256', $password) );


if ($numrows !=0) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbusername = $rows['username'];
        $dbpassword = $hash;

        if ($username===$dbusername&&$hash===$dbpassword) 
        {
            $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
            header("location: index.php?remarks=success");
        }
        else 
        {
            header("location: index.php?remarks=incorrect");
        }
    }
}
else
header("location: index.php?remarks=register");

}

else
header("location: index.php?remarks=other");

?>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="code_index.php">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div align="center">
                <?php
                $remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
                    if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="")
                    {
                        echo "Login Here<br/> <a     href='registration.php'>Or Click Here to Register.</a>";
                    }
                    if ($remarks=='register')
                    {
                        echo "That username Does not Exists.<br/><a href='registration.php'>Click Here to register.</a>";
                    }
                    if ($remarks=='incorrect')
                    {
                        echo "Incorrect Password.<br/>Please Re-enter Password";
                    }
                    if ($remarks=='success')
                    {
                        echo "Login Successful. <br/> <a href='membersarea.php'>Click Here to go to the Members Area.</a>";
                    }
                    if ($remarks=='other') {
                        echo "Please enter a Username and Password<br/><a href='registration.php'>Or Click Here to register.</a>";  
                    }
                ?>  
            </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your Username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're checking two things. If `$username === $dbusername` always matches, because that's how you're retrieving the row from the database. `$hash === $dbpassword` always matches, because you're assigning the value on the preceding line.

Comment: Try `$dbpassword = $rows['password']` for the assignment?

Comment: Plus you don't need any while - usernames should be unique.

Comment: And now as an answer, @andrewsi? :)

Comment: @CompuChip - feel free. I don't like claiming rep for something like this, but if you want to add an answer, go ahead :D

Comment: @andrewsi, I thought the rep was secondary to having answers as answers and comments as ... - well - comments. But it's your choice; I don't like claiming rep for someone else's answer. If you feel it more appropriate as a comment, feel free to leave it :)

Comment: @CompuChip - my access to SO tends to be a little spotty, so I've picked up the habit of answering in comments because I've not often got enough time to write what I consider a proper answer. I'm here to help people out, and if I happen to get reputation, it's a happy accident :D

Comment: Why are you writing a user access layer when a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) would already have a working implementation of this? `mysql_query` is being removed from PHP so you shouldn't even be using that approach in the first place.

Comment: @tadman you'll need to explain in English, or lamen terms, I'm new to php. And had no formal instruction. But I fixed my code (at least in getting it to do what I expected) and none of you are correct in your answers, but you did lead me to my answer

Comment: If you're new to PHP, your time is much better spent learning a robust framework like [Yii](http://yiiframework.com/) that has an [active community](http://www.yiiframework.com/community/) to help you learn and be productive. You're doing this the way sites were made in the 1990s and it's very, very hard compared to using a framework.

Comment: I'm doing it this way because I'm on a tight deadline and my tutor isn't much help. And it don't want to spend all of Christmas trying to write a site that needs a login & registration page, if I can get the mechanics of the php and mysql solved for this purpose I'll have more time to concentrate on the rest of the site and the documentation. If the course had been structured correctly I wouldn't have needed help. Thanks for your response. I'll look into your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign dbpassword from database

```
//$dbpassword = $hash; //This is wrong
```

Do it like this.

```
   $dbpassword = $rows['password'];

   if ($username===$dbusername&&$hash===$dbpassword)
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, seems all I'm doing is comparing the users inputed password against itself, because I've been staring at it so long, I became code blind. Always good to get another pair of eyes on it. Thanks everyone, I'll try the suggestions.

Comment: $dbusername = $rows['username'];
    $dbpassword = $hash;
   
    if ($username===$dbusername&&$password===$dbpassword)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        error_reporting(0);

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //sanitize username
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

        if(isset($username) && isset($password)) {
        include 'db.php';
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, salt
            FROM member
            WHERE username = '$username' ");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);          

        if ($numrows > 0) {
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $dbusername = $rows['username'];

                $salt = $rows['salt'];
                $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . hash('sha256', $password) );

                $dbpassword = $hash;

                if ($username==$dbusername && $hash==$dbpassword) 
                {
                    $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
                    header("location: index.php?remarks=success");
                }
                else 
                {
                    header("location: index.php?remarks=incorrect");
                }
            }
        }else{
            header("location: index.php?remarks=register");
        }

    }else{
        header("location: index.php?remarks=other");
    }
```